# Windows system CPU usage stays at 100%

Tags: windows-7, windows, performance

I use Windows 7, system has been working fine except that lately its has become relatively slow.

I opened tasked manager and noticed the CPU usage stays on 100% even when the only opened application is google chrome.

I have tried scanning my system with Microsoft Endpoint Antivirus and other Anti Malware but nothing was discovered.

Am totally confused right now and considering the option of re-installing a fresh copy of Windows 7.

What could be the possible cause of this issue?

[image]

Comment: Can you do a screenshot with "show all users processes"?

Comment: Have you checked this in clean boot or safe mode ?

Comment: @The_IT _Guy_You_Don't_Like not yet

Comment: Dumb question. what CPU is it?

Comment: @user256272 intel centrino

Comment: Might be a virus. There are viruses that use the resources of the infected computer to mine bitcoins. I would advice you to scan your system for malware.

Comment: @user256272  please what makes this a dump question?

Comment: Thanks to everyone. Even people that down voted me instead of answering my question. I have re installed my os and programs. Everything is okay. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

You should disable most of the applications that run at startup:

Run > msconfig > boot (uncheck all, exception made for your AV), reboot

Comment: Thanks for your answer I have re installed my os. Everythings fine now